# How to upload image using php , ajax on onchange event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am uploading an image on onchange event using  jquery ajax and php , the code is working but , but it is not uploading the image , showing undefined index photo on other page

index.php

```
<form id="reg" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" onchange="myfunction(this.form);" >
    <span id="photoid"></span>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
  function myfunction(theForm) {
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({      
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'regimg.php',
      data: formData, 
      success: function (data) { 
        $('#photoid').html(data); 
      },
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    })
  }
</script>
```

regimg.php

```
<?php 
  include 'db.php';
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
    $photo = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO img(image) VALUES('$photo')");
    if ($query AND move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'image/'.$photo))
    {
      echo 'Data has been added';
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'data could not be added';
    }
  }
?>
```

When I click on the file then there one error showing, undefined index photo.
Please help me out in this problem

Comment: `this` in your function is the `window`, not the `form` element. Try `var formData = new FormData(theForm);`

Comment: oh that simple mistake i was getting

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I added it as an answer

Answer (score 4):

`this` in your function is the `window`, not the `form` element. Change the FormData line to :

```
var formData = new FormData(theForm);
```